# How to wrap an async function inside AnyPublisher?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Lets say I want to create an asynchronous function that calls some random API and returns a random Int. I want wrap it using a future

```
func createFuture() -> Future<Int, Never> {
  return Future { promise in
    promise(.success(Int.random(1...10))
  }
}
```

This would return me the same output everytime. Instead i want to return AnyPublisher.

```
func createAnyPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {  //This is invalid
    return AnyPublisher<Int, Never> { seed in
        seed.success(Int.random(in: 1...10))
    }
}
```

A better example:

```
func guessNumber(num: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    asyncRandomNumber { winner in
        if num == winner {
            // return true
        } else {
            // return false
        }
    }
}

private func asyncRandomNumber(completion: (Int) -> Void) {
    completion(Int.random(in: 1...10))
}
```

How do you wrap that asyncRandomNumber ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Future` caches its result at initialisation, that's why you always see the same result. You can use `Just` instead if you want each subscriber to receive a different random number.

```
func randomIntPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
    Just(Int.random(in: 1...10)).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

If you want to wrap an async function in a `Publisher`, you can use `Future`, just make sure you call your function each time before creating a new subscription - this will make sure that you create a new `Future` and hence the result won't be cached and shared between the different subscribers.

```
func asyncRandomNumber(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        completion(Int.random(in: 1...100))
    }
}

func asyncRandomNumber() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
    Future { promise in
        asyncRandomNumber(completion: { num in
            promise(.success(num))
        })
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

asyncRandomNumber().sink(receiveValue: { print("First subscription received \($0)") }).store(in: &subscriptions)
asyncRandomNumber().sink(receiveValue: { print("Second subscription received \($0)") }).store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: I know, but there isn't like Rx (Observable.create { ... } ) in Combine?

Comment: @Godfather no, there's no such thing as `Observable` in Combine. There are different types of `Publisher`s, which are the equivalents. For your needs, `Just` is the `Publisher` that is best suited.

Comment: See my edits in the question "better example", how do you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Worth adding that `CombineExt` offers this as an extension:

https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineExt#anypublishercreate

For example:

```swift
static func fetchImage(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Error> {
    AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Error> .create { subscriber in
        WebImage.fetchImage(url: url) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let image):
                subscriber.send(image)
                subscriber.send(completion: .finished)
            case .failure(let error):
                subscriber.send(completion: .failure(error))
            }
        }
        return AnyCancellable {
```